# Fixing ListSliceContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, smoothing

I am trying to plot a sort of 3D anisotropic convection-diffusion equation. I want to use ListSliceContourPlot3D to show the solution `u[t,x,y,z]` at various time points. It kind of works, but it has this blue noise (away from the orange shells), which should not be there.

[image: Ugly plot]

My code is just:

```
ListSliceContourPlot3D[xyzw1, "CenterPlanes", DataRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-2, 2}}]
```

I thought rounding or thresholding might help, but it does not. I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

The data can be accessed [here](http://pastebin.com/SaWhxvm0).

Comment: To be of help, we will need access to your data.

Comment: @rcollyer What is the best way to add it to the post?

Comment: If it is small (not terribly likely), you can compress it and post it here. But, more viable solutions are to put it up on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com).

Comment: @rcollyer I've added it via pastebin; thanks for the suggestion

Comment: The problem is the 0 contour.  Try specifying the contour levels automatically:  `ListSliceContourPlot3D[xyzw1, "CenterPlanes", 
 DataRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-2, 2}}, 
 Contours -> Range[0.05, 0.8, .05]]`

Comment: `DataRange` also does nothing here (or it should) as the data is in the form `{x, y, z, f}`.

Comment: @JasonB. thanks for that! After extensive tweaking it works. Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that some of your data has a very small negative value

```
data = << "http://pastebin.com/raw/SaWhxvm0";
MinMax@N@(Last /@ data)
(* {-0.00056, 0.80093} *)
```

So the places where it crosses zero are drawn as a contour.  If it were a 2D plot, the `ToolTip` would have shown the contour value.  Whether this is noise or not, I can't say, but you can omit that contour by manually specifying the contours yourself.  As rcollyer points out, the `DataRange`
option is for when you have an array of values and need to specify the x,y, and z values.  But since you are giving those values in your data, this option is unnecessary here (if you want to restrict the plotted range you would use the `PlotRange` option).

```
ListSliceContourPlot3D[data, "CenterPlanes", 
 Contours -> Range[0.05, 0.8, .05]]
```

[image]